how to snap video div to 100% width on mobile
When I make my browser window thinner to replicate mobile sized - the images resize fine and fill 100% width...
But i can't get the videos to

fill 100% width
be aligned to the top - for some reason there is a lot of greenspace above and below it.

I've tried using media queries, and thought maybe just using % / auto values may be simpler - but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Multiple Responsive Slideshows</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: whitesmoke;
      margin: 0; /* Reset margin to 0 */
      padding: 20px; /* Reset padding to 0 */
    }

    .container {
      background-color: red;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      padding: 0px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column; /* Change flex direction to column */
      position: relative; /* Add position relative */
      margin-top: 0px; /* Add margin-top for spacing */
      overflow: none;
    }

    .slideshow-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
      max-height: 90vh;
      overflow: none;
      background-color: green; /* Set default background color to transparent */
      display: flex; /* Use flexbox layout */
      justify-content: center; /* Center items horizontally */
      align-items: center; /* Center items vertically */
    }

    .stage-bg {
      background-color: white; /* Set background color to red for carousel items with this class */
    }

    .carousel-item {
      text-align: center; /* Center images horizontally */
    }

    .slideshow-container img,
    .slideshow-container iframe {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      object-fit: contain;
    }

    /* Show arrows only on hover */
    .slideshow-container:hover .prev,
    .slideshow-container:hover .next {
      display: block;
    }

    .prev,
    .next {
      display: none;
      cursor: default; /* Change cursor to default */
      z-index: 1000;
      color: silver;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 30px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      width: auto;
      padding: 16px;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
      text-decoration: none; /* Remove underline */
    }

    .prev:hover,
    .next:hover {
      text-decoration: none; /* Remove underline */
      color: silver; /* Change color on hover */
    }

    .prev {
      left: 0;
    }

    .next {
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }

    .prev.disabled,
    .next.disabled {
      pointer-events: none;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }


    /* Custom CSS for text boxes */
    .textbox {
      background-color: white;
      max-width: 600px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-top: 20px; /* Add margin-top for spacing */
      margin-left: auto; /* Align to the right */
      margin-bottom: 20px; /* Add margin-bottom for spacing */
      text-align: left; /* Align text to the left */
    }

    .textbox p {
      margin: 0;
  
      }
   
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" style="max-width: 1000px">
  <div id="myCarousel1" class="slideshow-container carousel" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <!-- Image Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x600/?kitten">   
      </div>
      <div id="artists" class="carousel-item" style="padding: 20px">
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/335205129?h=1e30c728b8&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="640" height="640" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>      
        </div>
        
        
        <div id="nochill" class="carousel-item" style="padding: 20px">
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/143374377?h=760ef66606&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="800" height="450" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>  
        </div>

        
    </div>

    <!-- Navigation Arrows -->
    <a class="prev" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="prev">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="next">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <!-- Textbox -->
  <div class="textbox">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Nulla posuere, justo ut lacinia fermentum, nulla purus lacinia enim.</p>
  </div>
</div>

    
    
<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>




The body has padding: 20px;, should that be 0?

thanks, that padding is ok.
the real issue is if you run the code and view the page full size then make the browser thinner - the image scales perfectly down with no extra space above or below it.
but the two video slides they have a ton of greenspace above and below it. not sure why? im trying to get the video be aligned to the top, with no extra greenspace below it.

This is related to another question that I have answered before, where the video would not take the full width of the carousel. So this has a similar solution.
You can solve this is by using a wrapper div around the iframe and setting the padding-bottom to a percentage that represents the aspect ratio you want. This percentage is calculated as the height divided by the width times 100. For a 16:9 aspect ratio, this would be (9 / 16) * 100 = 56.25%. For a 4:5 aspect ratio, this would be (5 / 4) * 100 = 125% just like the last question.
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Multiple Responsive Slideshows</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: whitesmoke;
      margin: 0; /* Reset margin to 0 */
      padding: 20px; /* Reset padding to 0 */
    }

    .container {
      background-color: green;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      padding: 10px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center; 
    }
      
    .slideshow-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
      max-height: 90vh;
      overflow: none;
      background-color: green; /* Set default background color to transparent */
      display: flex; /* Use flexbox layout */
      justify-content: center; /* Center items horizontally */
      align-items: center; /* Center items vertically */
    }

    .stage-bg {
      background-color: white; /* Set background color to red for carousel items with this class */
    }

    .carousel-item {
      text-align: center; /* Center images horizontally */
    } 
      
    /* Custom CSS for text boxes */
    .textbox {
      background-color: white;
      max-width: 600px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-top: 20px; /* Add margin-top for spacing */
      margin-left: auto; /* Align to the right */
      margin-bottom: 20px; /* Add margin-bottom for spacing */
      text-align: left; /* Align text to the left */
    }

    .textbox p {
      margin: 0;
    }

    /* Custom aspect ratio for 4x5 video */
    .embed-responsive-4by5::before {
      padding-bottom: 125%;
    }

    .vidbox {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* for 16:9 aspect ratio */
    }

    .vidbox iframe {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .embed-responsive-4by5 .vidbox {
      padding-bottom: 125%; /* for 4:5 aspect ratio */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container" style="max-width: 1000px;">
  <div id="myCarousel1" class="slideshow-container carousel" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <!-- Image Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x600/?kitten" alt="...">
      </div>
      
      <!-- Video Slide 1-->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div id="nochill" class="vidbox embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/143374377?h=760ef66606&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>  
      </div>

     <!-- Video Slide 2 -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="phonewrapper embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by5">
          <div id="phone" class="vidbox">
            <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/912417077?badge=0&autopause=0&player_id=0&app_id=58479" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x800/?sea" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <!-- Navigation Arrows -->
    <a class="prev" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="prev">❮</a>
    <a class="next" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="next">❯</a>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Textbox -->
  <div class="textbox">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Nulla posuere, justo ut lacinia fermentum, nulla purus lacinia enim.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

